# colorbox headache

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, colorbox

I've made a playlist that pulls information from an xml file. the videos are called by clicking a hyperlink. I am trying to add colorbox and I've gotten the box to come up but cant figure out for the life of me how to get the videos to open into the colorbox. Here is the code im using:

```
$(function() {
   /* be sure data is defined here */
$( data ).find("chapter").each(function() {

    var $chapter = $('<li class="chaptertitle"/>')
    .append('<img class="img-swap" src="http://sandbox.kalliance.com/demo/images/plus.png" class="img-swap" />')
    .append('<p align="left" class="pc-left">' + $(this).attr("label") + '<p align="right" class="pc-right">Duration</p>')
    .append('<ul/>')
    .appendTo( '#screens' );
    $(this).find('screen').each(function() {
        time=$(this).find('screen').attr('duration')
        $("#screens").append(time)
         $('#screens ul:last')
         .append('<li class="screentitle"/>')
         .find('li:last')
         .append('<p align="left" class="p-left"><a href="'+streamer+''+filenum+'/streams/_definst_/' + $(this).attr('path') + '" id="colorbox-load">' + $(this).attr('label') + ' </a></p>  <p align="right" class="p-right">'+ $(this).attr("duration")+'</p>');

         //tgonzalez - create the modal window for the video

       $("#colorbox-load").click(function() {
        $.colorbox({inline:true, width:960, height:540, opacity:0.8 });
```

Answer (score 0):

colorbox API of jquery takes a reference of a container which you are trying to open in the colorbox. try this

```
$.colorbox({href: "#divIdHere", inline:true, width:960, height:540, opacity:0.8 });
```

Comment: I tried your suggestion and even created a div for id="player" in the main html page but it still shows a empty white box.